# Installing mono on raspberry without precompilation

Tags: mono

When installing mono on raspberry, using the official way described on mono website, i get a bunch of precompilation

example:

```
Mono precompiling /usr/lib/mono/4.5/mcs.exe for arm...
```

It takes lot of time, and i also got some raspberry rebooting during the task :(

is there a way to install mono without this precompilation stage ?

Comment: what version of mono did you install btw?

Comment: The latest available through the repository : 5.16.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the person in charge of Mono packaging in Microsoft, [this problem is fixed in the preview (not stable) channel which brings you Mono 5.18](https://twitter.com/directhex/status/1067995402325164032): https://www.mono-project.com/download/preview/.

Comment: Thanks for the information ! i was unable to find this on the mono official website. so i'll wait for the 5.18 when stable.

Comment: Yes i mean i was unable to find why it was precompiling ;) i'll wait for the stable release as mono is used in a production environment here :)

Comment: but test with 5.18 first, and tell us if it works, then migrate production at your own pace